# Find the volume formed by rotating the region bounded by $y = e^{-x} \sin x$, $x\ge 0$ about $y =0$.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

> Find the volume formed by rotating the region bounded by $y = e^{-x} \sin x$, $x\ge 0$ about $y =0$.

I tried to graph this using Wolfram Alpha, but it didn't help.  I don't know how to start or graph this.

Comment: The answer is pi/8 by the way in my homework

Comment: It is kind of like $y=\sin x$ except there is a strong damping factor $e^{-x}$.
It still crosses the $x$-axis at $x=\pi,2\pi,3\pi$ and so on but after a short while is awfully close to the $x$-axis. The volume is equal to 
$\int_0^\infty \pi e^{-2x} \sin^2 x\,dx$. The integral requires some work. It may be useful to recall that $\sin^2 x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$.

Comment: When you solved it did you graph it? It makes sense once i zoom in on the graph, but I fear if i do not have the graph I cannot solve these types of problems... :(

Comment: I sort of graphed it. Was smoking outside without drawing tools, so had to imagine drawing.  I cannot solve this kind of problem either unless I at least *imagine* drawing the picture.

Comment: gg, should i just test a couple points such that x>=0, and then graph it like that? Honestly without the picture these problems are impossible for me :/

Comment: Testing a few points can't hurt, but imagining $e^{-x}\sin x$ is more like recalling what $\sin x$ and $e^{-x}$ look like.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = e^{-x} \sin x$$
Your volume can be found using cylindrical coordinates :

\begin{align}
\mathcal{V}\equiv\int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{f(x)} r dr d\theta dx &= 2\pi \int\limits_0^\infty\int\limits_0^{f(x)} r dr dx\\
&=\pi \int\limits_0^\infty f^2(x) dx =\pi \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x}\sin^2x dx = \pi \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x}\dfrac{1-\cos 2x}{2}dx\\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{2} \left\lbrace \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x}dx -\dfrac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x}\left[e^{2ix} + e^{-2ix}\right]dx\right\rbrace\\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{2} \left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{2} -\dfrac{1}{2} \left[\dfrac{e^{-2(1-i)x}}{-2(1-i)} + \dfrac{e^{-2(1+i)x}}{-2(1+i)}\right]_0^\infty\right\rbrace\\
&=  \dfrac{\pi}{2} \left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{2} +\left[\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{4} \left(\dfrac{e^{2ix}}{1-i} + \dfrac{e^{-2ix}}{1+i}\right)\right]_0^\infty\right\rbrace\\
&=  \dfrac{\pi}{2} \left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{2} +\left[\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{4} \left(\dfrac{e^{2ix}}{1-i} + \dfrac{e^{-2ix}}{1+i}\right)\right]_0^\infty\right\rbrace\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2} \left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{2} +\left[\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{8} \left((1+i)e^{2ix} + (1-i)e^{-2ix}\right)\right]_0^\infty\right\rbrace\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2} \left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{2} +\left[\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{4} \left(\cos 2x - \sin 2x\right)\right]_0^\infty\right\rbrace\\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{2} \left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{4}\right\rbrace\\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{8}
\end{align}

Comment: lel im in high school we havent learnt that yet, but thanks alot :D

Comment: @muntasir What method did you learn ?

Comment: We just do shell method and disk method

Answer (score 0):

Here is a graph from $0$ to $\pi$, the integral you already know from  André ...

[image]